# RecyclerView goes out of Sync

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have created a firebase chat. It uses a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews` to show the messages. I'm changing the `CardView` Gravity inside the `OnBindViewHolder` method of `RecyclerView.Adapter`, so the senders messages will be on one side and others in other side(WhatsApp).
Here is my code,

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        
        final MessageItem messageItem = messageItems.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(messageItem.getSenderName());
        holder.message.setText(messageItem.getMessage());
        
        if(messageItem.getFrom() == new UserLocalStore(context).getUserDetails().getId()){
            holder.linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }

    }
```

This works fine when loading the messages for the first time[image]

But goes out of sync as i scroll though or send a new message
[image]

What could be the reason for this? I have tried updating the gravity inside `onViewAttachedToWindow` and `onViewRecycled` methods too.

Comment: You need an else clause in your onBind... to set it back to left because your views get recycled.

Comment: Thanks naveed, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this code

```
if(messageItem.getFrom() == new UserLocalStore(context).getUserDetails().getId()){
    holder.linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}else{
    holder.linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

You need a to set a left gravity in else because recyclerview recycled view when you scroll